# Get the value of a cell and do something based on the number in that cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to create some code in exel that looks at the value of a cell and then performs a `Hide` action if the number in the cell is less than 99.

Here is my idea:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim CellValue As Integer
CellValue = Target.Value("$D$68")

If CellValue <= 99 Then
    Rows("70:77").Hidden = True
    Else
        Rows("70:77").Hidden = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        End If
End Sub
```

I believe the problem here is that I cannot obtain the a reference to that cell? 
How could I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you should replace `CellValue = Target.Value("$D$68")` by `CellValue = Target.Value` - Target as range has everything to return value, you have wrong syntax.

Manually value from `D68` may be returned as `CellValue = Range("D68").Value`.

Comment: Thanks @Peter L!, I decided to go for the manual cell value and it works!